# Disable setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, module, setup-di-compile

Maybe this is a very silly question. I can not understand why I must run the command `setup:di:compile` every time I make changes to custom modules, to see the results when I am in developer mode.

Can it be disabled?

Comment: Sounds like you have cache enabled. as you shouldn't be required to do anything to get your changes to show. the only reason you would need to empty generated is if the constructors have changed in any way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to run it. You can simply delete the directories under var/generation (or under generated/ after 2.2). Be careful not to the delete the **.htaccess file**. You only really ever need to do this when you create a new constructor or change or reorder the arguments being passed into one of your class constructors.

For 2.2 and onwards, [Magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html) suggests using this command:

```
rm -rf <magento_root>/generated/metadata/* <magento_root>/generated/code/*
```

Answer (score 5):

You should **not** run setup:di:compile in developer mode!

This command need only for production mode.

Comment: But if don't run it I can't see some changes I make to my custom extension. For example, when I add a new class to my module, it is not recognized until I run setup:di:compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try cleanup var/di and var/generate folder and try one more time